# CSS height property resizes iframe wrong

Tags: html, css, iframe

I'm having this Page, Where an iframe is supposed to load. The frame is of size 1024x768. But for some reason, the frame loads very small (Probably a 300x200). My code currently looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./design.css">

    <style>
    .edetail_frame {
      border-radius: 25px;
        height: 1024;
        width:768;
        display:inline-block;
        overflow: hidden;
        box-shadow: 5px 5px 7px  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h3 style ="font-family:Open Sans">SlideShow</h3>

<div class="col-sm-10 ">
<div class="row fill-height">
<div class="edetail_frame" style="flex-basis: 700px">

<iframe src="frame.html" frameborder="0" id="edetail_frame" scrolling="no"></iframe></div>
</div></div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you looked into dev console where it gets its computed height and width from

Comment: set `height` and `width` from `iframe` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `#`id of iframe rather then using class to target

```
#edetail_frame{
        border-radius: 25px;
        height: 1024px;
        width:768px;
        display:inline-block;
        overflow: hidden;
        box-shadow: 5px 5px 7px  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

If using class then

```
.edetail_frame {
      border-radius: 25px;
        height: 1024px;
        width:768px;
        display:inline-block;
        overflow: hidden;
        box-shadow: 5px 5px 7px  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }
.edetail_frame iframe{
        height: 100%; 
        width: 100%;
}
```

Don't forget to use units of your dimension like `px` `em` etc

Answer (score 3):

Should put the `width` and `height` directly in in the iframe tag

```
<iframe src="frame.html" frameborder="0" id="edetail_frame" width="768" height="1024" scrolling="no"></iframe></div>
```

If you want to use css, you need to put `px`